# Bluetooth Serial Comms Without Pairing

Tags: android, bluetooth, serial-port

Can someone point me in the right direction please?!

I am trying to connect to an industrial product using Android over Bluetooth. The device does not support pairing. I have written an application in WM6.5 and that works fine.

The sequence of events is:

Discover device and establish a Bluetooth Serial connection (the device does not support passkeys/pairing).
Request a key from the product (by sending a hex string)
Read string and send back a response based on the key and a user entered password (by responding with another hex string).

Is there an example anywhere that I can download?

I have downloaded some BT serial terminal emulators but they all want to pair with the device.

In Windows 7 you can simply search, connect and choose to connect without pairing and then the device appear as a BT serial port.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Pairing is not something that a remote device either supports or doesn't support.  Your Android can pair to any Bluetooth device it finds.  This only means that it records the device's MAC address and friendly name for future reference.  If your device has a PIN you may need to enter that at pairing time and the Android will record that too.